# How to model stocks of a warehouse time series?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Warehouse buys products from producer irregularly in bulk quantities. If the warehouse buys a lot of product units at one time the warehouse stops buying for several weeks (let's say week is a time unit). The more they buy (i.e. because of the price promotion), the farther they postpone future buying. I have time series of producer sales to warehouse but I don't know how many units leaks out of the warehouse to retailers - retail shops may also buy irregularly from the warehouse. What is the approach to model stocks of the warehouse from the producer point of view?

How many units the warehouse will buy in the next future week? 
How much of the current producer sales to warehouse is because of the low stocks in the preceding weeks?

Comment: Do you know the reorder points of the goods at the warehouse?  What sort of leadtimes are you dealing with?

Comment: I have only one variable. Sales orders showing traffic from producer to warehouse. I dont know anything about re-orders from warehouse to retailers (if that is what you mean). The time series units are weeks. Some weeks are empty - there are no orders from warehouse in that weeks. Assumptions: 1. Warehouse keeps the lowest stocks as they can (keeping stocks means costs). 2. Warehouse always wants to have SOME stocks. They don't want to be out of product because then retailers may buy it in another warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

Prz.  In general an ARIMA model is an optimization of the number of previous periods to use in the weighting scheme AND the values of the coefficients . You are assuming 3 periods and the coefficients are equal. Care must be taken to identify level shifts , seasonal pulses, pulses and Local time trends while ensuring that the parameters (coefficients) haven't changed over tome and that the error variance is homogeneous. For more on ARIMA modelling and Intervention Detection please see work by Tsay http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf and perhaps some of my previous posts here at SE https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3382/irishstat?tab=activity. Hope this helps. If you wish to post an example time series, I will try and give you some pointers on this data.

Answer (score 0):

Some idea is like this:

**Y(t) = constant - [Y(t-1) +Y(t-2) +Y(t-3)]**

Where *[Y(t-1) +Y(t-2) +Y(t-3)]* means the sum of recent past orders from the warehouse. Here in this example I used past 3 observations but the number of observations summed may be optimized.

Instead of constant one might use rolling average multiplied by the number of observations summed +1.